# Laravel setting up a simple controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

```
<?php 

class TasksController extends BaseController {

  public function index()
  {
      return 'show all tasks.';

  }

}


?>
```

That's what I did very simple. But when I go to localhost:8888/tasks
it doesn't show the result it shows Whoops! Something went wrong.
What could possibly be the problem, such a simple code? By the way I just set up Laravel recently.

Comment: How is your `routes.php` being setup? And you can enable debugging by going to your `/config/app.php` and set debug to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers don't do anything until you point a route at them, via `app/routes.php`.

http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Adding:

```
Route::get('tasks', 'TasksController@index');
```

is likely to do the trick.

Comment: You are right hahaha! Thanks so much -.- I ignored the beginning of the video I'm watching